# How to push changes from a forked project to the original project?

Tags: github, git-push

I’m supposed to work on my client's project on GitHub, where the changes would be on his repository.  I tried to follow the fork example, but could only get the changes to go to my account repository?

In the example on GitHub, to fork a repo, they create a remote  called `upstream` to point to the original project.  I can get the changes from it by

```
get fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master
```

I was able to upload the changes into my repo by

```
git push –u  origin
```

which copied my changes to my account.

I tried

```
git push –u upstream
```

To push my changes on the original account. I got the following error

> You can’t push to git://github.com.octocat/SpoonKnife.git
>   use git@github.comoctocat/Spoon0-Knife.git

Comment: Well, if you don't have write access to the client's repository you cannot push the changes to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, in order to collaborate with your client, you've got two main options:

- Send your client a `pull request` (more info on this in this **[GitHub help item](http://help.github.com/send-pull-requests/)**). This allows your client to review, discuss and/or request some changes to your proposal before merging it.
- Request from your client to be added as a `committer` to their project. This would allow you to directly push your commits to their repository, without the need for a fork/cloned repository on your side.

As a side note, [Spoon-Knife.git](https://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife) is one of GitHub's read-only repository (used for demonstration purpose) and you will not be able to commit to that (unless your client **is** GitHub). Thus, your client's `upstream` git remote should point to a different repository

Here are the steps (to be followed after you forked and cloned the repository to your local disk):

1. Remove the upstream reference: `git remote rm upstream`
2. Add in your client's info - `git remote add upstream git@xxxxxx`
3. Push your changes - `git push -u upstream master` . `git push -u` will set the HEAD of the remote repository.
4. Same if you want to pull - `git pull upstream master`

If you prefer the name origin replace upstream with origin, but still follow step 1 to remove the reference to Spoon-Knife.git. Then in step 2 - `git remote add origin git@xxxx`.

Answer (score 1):

git://github.com.octocat/SpoonKnife.git is a read-only URL. As GitHub suggests, the corresponding write-able URL is git@github.comoctocat/Spoon0-Knife.git.
If you want to be able to push on the upstream repository, you will have to ask (to the upstream team, i.e., your customer) to be added as a committer.